Can not create the most simple kubernetes cluster because of incorrect apiVersion for kind
I am following this guide to create a simple kubernetes cluster on my machine: https://www.appvia.io/blog/tutorial-deploy-kubernetes-cluster
When trying to run kind create cluster --name mycluster --config config/kind.config.yaml --wait 5m
I am always getting error:
Creating cluster "kind" ...
ERROR: failed to create cluster: could not determine kind / apiVersion for config: yaml: line 4: did not find expected key

I have tried so many different apiVersion for kind:
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
 extraPortMappings:
 - containerPort: 30080
   hostPort: 80
   listenAddress: "0.0.0.0"
   protocol: TCP

And still nothing. What is the correct apiVersion for kind ? How to start it?
[root@grpc-collector config]# kind version kind v0.8.1 go1.14.2 linux/amd64

The error message is kinda misleading here, you just didn't intend your YAML file properly.
This is a common issue and happens quite easily when writing k8s YAML files without IDE support. Try with this correctly intended version
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 30080
        hostPort: 80
        listenAddress: "0.0.0.0"
        protocol: TCP

